# NullPointerException when invoking method with Mockito in Service test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, springmockito

The main problem is that the *convertToMultipartImage* method in the *AzureCloudStorageService* class is returning null unexpectedly during testing, despite the mocking setup seeming correct. This suggests that there may be an issue with how the *ModelMapper* is being used or configured in the test environment.

```
@Service
public class AzureCloudStorageService implements FileService {
    private final String connectionString;
    private final String containerName;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public AzureCloudStorageService(@Autowired PropertyResolver propertyResolver,
        ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.connectionString = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.connection.string");
        this.containerName = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.container.name");
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
public MultipartFile convertToMultipartImage(String image) {
        try {
            return modelMapper.map(image, MultipartFile.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadRequestException(ErrorMessage.MULTIPART_FILE_BAD_REQUEST + image);
        }
    }
```

Test class with setup:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class AzureCloudStorageServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Mock
    private AzureCloudStorageService azureCloudStorageService;

    @Test
    void convertToMultipartImage(){
        MultipartFile multipartFile = ModelUtils.getFile();
        String image = "Image";
        when(modelMapper.map(image, MultipartFile.class)).thenReturn(multipartFile);
        MultipartFile actual = azureCloudStorageService.convertToMultipartImage("Image");
            assertEquals(multipartFile,  actual);
    }
}
```

The full stacktrace is as follows:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile@441cc260
Actual   :null
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageServiceTest.convertToMultipartImage(AzureCloudStorageServiceTest.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you please share the related stacktrace?

Comment: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:---
Expected :org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile@441cc260  ------
Actual   :null---
---------------------------
If you about this, because i dont know what is stacktrace, sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q8nbLl2t-3Sa2NkmSO3S9lTdARkyCgOEpXxJ0s2gLPA/edit?usp=sharing  link on Screenshot

Comment: Please copy and paste the stacktrace as part of you question. Do not link images moreover so from external sources.

Comment: added stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems stems from the wrong way you do your mocks. In your code you do the following:

```
@Mock
private AzureCloudStorageService azureCloudStorageService;
```

Which effectively returns a mocked instance of `AzureCloudStorageService`. This is not what you want and need for this case, as this is what you need to test (i.e the unit under test). What you need to do though is to manually instantiate the `AzureCloudStorageService` by calling its constructor and passing in the mocked `ModelMapper` as well as `PropertyResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
@Mock
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

Use into the method or in @Before method:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = Mockito.mock(ModelMapper.class);
```

It is working for me:

```
ServicioCalls servicioCalls = Mockito.mock(ServicioCalls.class);
    EncapsulatedError<?> encapsulatedError = new EncapsulatedError<>(SpResult.SUCCESS_CODE, SpResult.OK, 0, null);
   Mockito.doReturn(encapsulatedError).when(servicioCalls).obtenerCalls(anyString(), anyString(), anyLong());
```

Comment: It doesn`t help me, because this is the same code what I did and program throws me the same exception, thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

It`s working properly and covering my method and constructor) Thank you akortex

```
@Test
    void convertToMultipartImage(){
        MultipartFile multipartFile = Mockito.mock(MultipartFile.class);
        AzureCloudStorageService azureCloudStorageService = new AzureCloudStorageService(propertyResolver, modelMapper);
        String image = "Image";
        when(modelMapper.map(image, MultipartFile.class)).thenReturn(multipartFile);
            assertEquals(multipartFile, azureCloudStorageService.convertToMultipartImage("Image"));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try with it:

Change this:

```
when(modelMapper.map(image, MultipartFile.class)).thenReturn(multipartFile);
```

By this:

```
Mockito.doReturn(modelMapper).when(modelMapper).map(anyString(), any());
```

And set to azureCloudStorageService the mockling object modelMapper previos to call:

```
azureCloudStorageService.setModelMapper(modelMapper);
MultipartFile actual = azureCloudStorageService.convertToMultipartImage("Image");
assertEquals(multipartFile,  actual);
```

Comment: I do not think this is the correct approach. Adding a `setter` only to pass in the the mocked instance effectively denies the class of being immutable. What he needs to do is to pass in the mocked dependencies through the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, do you can use inheritance, creates a class dummy like it

```
private static class CallsRestStub extends CallsRest {

 }
```

When CallsRest is the original class and modelMapper protected.
With it you can creates a instance of CallsRestStub instead CallSRest and sets to it the mocking object